# React cloneElement is not working for functional component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, clone-element

I would like to add some props to my component using `{React.cloneElement(<MyComponent />, { onClick: () => console.log('click'), style: {background: 'red'} })}`

Full code:

```
const MyComponent = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      foooo
    </div>
  );
};

....
return React.cloneElement(<MyComponent />, { onClick: () => console.log('click'), style: {background: 'red'} })
```

But `props` are not passed into my component.

When I use:

```
return React.cloneElement(<div>foooo</div>, { onClick: () => console.log('click'), style: {background: 'red'} })
```

Props are working. Why? I don`t understand why.

Comment: cloneElement passes the props to the component, but your component must accept the props as arguments, otherwise the props are not applied. See answer by @SalientBrain

Answer (score 4):

Why would you use `cloneElement` when you got JSX available (can conclude it from `MyComponents` syntax).

Instead do:

```
<MyComponent
  onClick={() => console.log("click")}
  style={{ background: "red" }}
/>
```

And fix your component:

```
const MyComponent = ({ style, onClick }) => {
  return <div onClick={onClick} style={style}>foooo</div>;
}
```

JSX [is sugar syntax](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#cloneelement) for `createElement` / `cloneElement`.

```
React.cloneElement(
  element,
  [props],
  [...children]
)
```

React.cloneElement() is almost equivalent to:

```
<element.type {...element.props} {...props}>{children}</element.type>
```

Therefore the right syntax:

```
const onClick = () => console.log('click');
const style = {background: 'red'};

// Exatcly the same effect as <MyComponent .../> above
React.cloneElement(<MyComponent/>, {onClick, style}, null);
```

[image: Edit intelligent-architecture-9modf]

Comment: And in sandbox we see that style is not applied. And also onClick works from original component, not from clone! WHY?

Comment: @SalientBrain I fixed the example, just pass the style prop in `MyComponent`. Not sure about your second part of the question

Comment: Yes. Please check my answer.

Answer (score 4):

You need to apply props inside you component:

```
export const Test = (props: any) => {
  return (<button {...props}>Click Me</button>);
}
```

In this case you can set props using

```
React.cloneElement(<MyComponent/>, props, null);
```

but I do not recommend cloning (it is too heavy)
I think that it is better to use special render function in props:

```
export const Wrapper = (props: {render: (props: any) => any}) => {
    const childProps = {style: {background: 'red'}, onClick: () => { console.log('click'); }};
    if (props.render){
      return props.render(childProps);
    } else {
      return <></>;
    }
  }
// ...
// usage:
export default function App() {      
  return (
    <div className="App">      
      <Wrapper render={(props)=>{
        return <button {...props}>TEST</button>;
      }}/>      
    </div>
  );
}
```